# Check if DropTable in DAO was successful

Tags: php, yii2, dao

I'm looking at executing a query like this:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->dropTable($r)
```

I have been using `execute()` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#dropTable()-detail in order to do so, but I'm unsure from the docs if I should be doing this. I in particular want to return the success or failure of dropping a table in this instance. What is the correct way? I see that execute only seems to return the number of rows affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the execute return the number of the row affect. In this case one row is affected . For a better error mnaagement you can also manage the error situation

adding

```
use yii\base\Exception;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
```

and the in you function adding

```
    try {
     Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->dropTable($r)->execute();
    }
    catch (\yii\db\Exception $e) {
        // yii db exception 
        $populateError =  $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        // not a db exception
        $populateError = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

In this way if you have an error (eg: the table to be  dropped not exist)  you can manage it.

Comment: Thanks, I had just started doing this as it was the only way I thought available. Glad I was on the right tracks. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes the try cath is a few tedious but is the most powerful way for these situations